VSTO - Visual Studio Tool Office
I have a group of Word templates and I want to create a Add-in Word (app VSTO - Visual Studio Tools Office ) through which I can display the template I would like to work on and make the necessary modifications to it.
I have already created a project (C#) for one Word file template, but through the same project I want to control other templates

What is your question? You need to be a lot more specific than that.

Do you want to display the templates so that you can make permanent changes to the template? Or, are you wanting to create new documents based on the template that you can customize for single use? The latter is the usual use for templates. It is unusual to be opening a template for editing after it is ready for use.
Here is a link to my page on templates. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm

If I were doing this, I suspect that I would try it in vba with a global template. I would add a custom Ribbon tab that has menus for the templates. This can be dynamic so that by moving templates in and out of folders. If you would like me to share more information on this, let me know. Here are a couple of good starter links: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/dynamic_ribbon_menu.html Once set up, the maintenance on such a system is very easy and can be done without technical knowledge.

I have succeeded in creating code that displays each form when the corresponding button is pressed
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wdApplication = Globals.ThisDocument.Application;
        wdApplication.Documents.Add(@"C:\dossier\MODEL1.dotx");

